# add a ListViewItem to two or more ListView Items Collection?

Tags: c#, listviewitem

```
List<Profile> listProf = new List<Profile>();
...
...
foreach (Profile p in listProf)
{
   ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem();
   Item.Text = p.Name;
   Item.Tag = p;
   ListView1.Items.Add(Item);
   ListView2.Items.Add(Item);
}
```

In this instance how would I get this `Item` into both ListViews? I just get the error that I need to clone it. how can I do this? I'm not quite sure even the reason why a ListView would want to be so picky either.

How can I add an item to more than one ListViewCollection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach(var p in listProf)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem{Text = p.Name, Tag = p};
    ListView1.Items.Add(item);
    ListView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
}
```

Comment: your a saint among men

Answer (score 0):

The reason the ListView is so "picky" is because the IsSelected flag in particular is kept at the ListViewItem level... so if you added it to multiple ListViews then selected in one would be selected in all.

Fortunately ListViewItem has a .Clone() method.

Comment: right, my question was more along the lines of "how do I use .Clone() if it's the best solution"